# Postgresssql Advanced Join

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgresssql.
I have two table like this

**Table A**

```
id      |value  | type1  | type2  | type3
bigint  |text   | bigint | bigint | bigint
```

**Table B**

```
Id      | description
bigint  | text
```

Table A's type1,type2,type3 is the ids of Table B but **not foreign key** constraint.

I have to retrieve like this

```
Select a.id,
       a.value,
       b.description1(as of a.type1),
       b.description1(as of a.type1),
       b.description1(as of a.type1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to many columns you should consider change your db design

TableA

```
   id   | value        
    1   | <something>
    2   | <something>
```

TableAType

```
    id  | TableA.id | type_id | typeValue
     1  |     1     | type1   | bigint
     2  |     1     | type2   | bigint
     3  |     1     | type3   | bigint
           .....
     4  |     1     | typeN   | bigint
```

TableB (type_description)

```
Id      | description
bigint  | text
```

Then your query become more simple and isn't affected when you add/remove types.

```
SELECT TB.Description, TT.TypeValue
FROM TableAType TT
JOIN TableB     TB
  ON TT.Type_id = TB.id
```

Then you can use a [**PIVOT**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905) to get the tabular data. Again the advantage is you can delete remove types, and your query doesnt change, only need update the types tables.

Answer (score 0):

You should (LEFT) JOIN tableB 3 times, and use a different alias for each one.

```
select id, value, 
           type1, t1.description descri1, 
           type2, t2.description descri2,
           type3, t3.description descri3
from       tableA ta
left  join tableB t1
on         ta.type1 = t1.id 
left  join tableB t2
on         ta.type2 = t2.id 
left  join tableB t3
on         ta.type3 = t3.id;
```

Comment: I have 10 columns like that.Here for reference i put 3.

Comment: @madhu Well then you need to do that 10 times.

Comment: Any other better way?

Comment: IMHO I'd rather use another table, but yes, you must add it 10 times.